# PostgreSQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds

Tags: postgresql, docker, zabbix

I have a problem creating a `zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql:latest` container says that the PostgreSQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds,and it does not happen there. I'm new to docker and I have little idea why this happens, I read somewhere that giving value to `DB_SERVER_ROOT_USER = "zabbix"` was solved but it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
docker run -e DB_SERVER_ROOT_USER="zabbix" zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql:latest
** Deploying Zabbix frontend (nginx) with postgresql database
** Preparing the system
** Preparing Zabbix web-interface
*********************
* DB_SERVER_HOST: postgres-server
* DB_SERVER_PORT: 5432
* DB_SERVER_DBNAME: zabbix
* DB_SERVER_ZBX_USER: zabbix
* DB_SERVER_ZBX_PASS: zabbix
***********************
**** PostgreSQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...
**** PostgreSQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...
**** PostgreSQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...
```

Answer (score 3):

In new versions of Docker, it is considered correct to use the "Network"

step 1:

> docker network create zabbix-network

for convenience, you can create a volume for the database:

> docker volume create zabbix-postgres-volume

step 2: run postgres image

> docker run -d -it --name zabbix-postgres --network zabbix-network -e
>   POSTGRES_USER=zabbix -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=zabbix -v
>   zabbix-posgres-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres

step 3: run zabbix-server image

> docker run -it -d --name zabbix-server --network zabbix-network -p
>   10051:10051 -e DB_SERVER_HOST=zabbix-postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=zabbix
>   -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=zabbix zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql

step 4:

Now you can check the correct connection by logging in PostgreSQL

> docker exec -it zabbix-postgres sh

```
# su

root@234afbed:/# psql -U zabbix

zabbix=# \dt
```

if everything is correct, then you should see 149 tables created in the database

Answer (score 2):

[zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql](https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql/) image is a Zabbix frontend based on Nginx with PostgreSQL database support. It doesn't have PostgreSQL database inside it. Zabbix web interface is a part of Zabbix software. It is used to manage resources under monitoring and view monitoring statistics.

It should be deployed as an addition to Zabbix server ([zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql](https://hub.docker.com/r/zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql/)) and PostrgreSQL ([postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)) database.

There is a `docker-compose.yaml` example, which can help you to achieve your goal:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: zabbix
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: zabbix
      POSTGRES_DB: zabbix
  zabbix-server:
    image: zabbix/zabbix-server-pgsql
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_SERVER_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: zabbix
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: zabbix
      POSTGRES_DB: zabbix
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  zabbix-web:
    image: zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql
    restart: always
    environment:
      ZBX_SERVER_HOST: zabbix-server
      DB_SERVER_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: zabbix
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: zabbix
      POSTGRES_DB: zabbix
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - zabbix-server
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Above `docker-compose.yaml` allows to deploy PostgreSQL, Zabbix server and Zabbix Web frontend.

After `docker-compose up` Zabbix interface will be available on `localhost:8080`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have a question this is a single container or several since I see that it makes use of 3 images? The problem is that I must create only one zabbix container operating with Nginx and PostgreSQL, to monitor a server that is another container.

Comment: The above example has three containers. You need only `zabbix-web` part if you already have container with Zabbix server and PostgreSQL.

Comment: For example I could mount on a CentOS container, a Zabbix web server that works with Nginx and PostgreSQL. Excuse me if my questions are very obvious or silly I'm new to this and some things I do not understand well. @Nickolay

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the zabbix container with --network=host  (only for linux)

I had a similar issue and solved after the inclusion of --network

You can find more details here.
[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 0):

in file ./zbx_env/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hda.conf

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

change to

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
```